# No update since last couple of days on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, updates

Everything was going fine up until now. But since last couple of days i don't see any updates available for my system.

When I do `sudo-apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` ... It simply returns with 0 to be upgraded, 0 to be installed..

So, I was wondering if anything wrong has happened or is it that Ubuntu itself hasn't pushed any updates in past few days?

PS: My system is working fine otherwise.

Comment: Do you expect updates every single day? Most of the most critical updates are in the first week after a new Ubuntu version is released, after that are just maintainence and security updates. I personaly set the update manager to run every week.

Comment: Execute the command  update-manager -c -d  to check the system is up to date.

Comment: You can open a terminal and enter `sudo less /var/log/dpkg.log` and `sudo less /var/log/dpkg.log.1` to check when you had your last updates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checking https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-security-announce/2014-December/date.html it looks like there hasn't been any security updates since December 22.

You can check here for any more changes https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/?C=M;O=A.

As far as security updates are concerned, you can get email alerts by signing up for the mailing list or rss feed [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/usn/).